# Using quotes in SQLite an Android

Tags: android, database, string, sqlite, quotes

I have a doubt about a code line in an android app with SQlite:

```
if(db != null)
    {
        db.delete("Users", null, null);

        //Insert 5 users
        for(int i=1; i<=5; i++)
        {
            //Generate the data
            int code = i;
            String name = "User" + i;

            //Insert data on table Users
            db.execSQL("INSERT INTO Users (code, name) " +
                       "VALUES (" + code + ", '" + name +"')");
        }
    }
```

All the code work perfectly, but in the line: `db.execSQL("INSERT INTO Users (code, name) " + "VALUES (" + code + ", '" + name +"')");` if I delete the `'`character, the app crashes. Can anyone tell me why I must to use the `'`character and also the `"`? Why the `"` are not enough?

I'm a noob, sorry if my question is too basic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, good lord, never write SQL like that. Do what the other answer(s) say to do inserts.

Second, it doesn't work because the name column is a string and so it needs to be quoted in an insert statement. The SQL that does the insert is:

```
INSERT INTO Users (code, name) VALUES (666, 'Bruce Dickinson')
```

Comment: So,  if I would write `INSERT INTO Users (code, name) VALUES (666, "Bruce Dickinson")` that would not work? I'm starting in SQLite and databases and I don't understand in what cases I must to use the " or the ' symbols. I read some information in the official website but I could not find clear information about it or, maybe, i don't understand it. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: You need to understand the difference between the string that you need to send to SQLite, and the string that you see in your IDE. The string I gave above is what you need to send to the database, not the string you see in your text editor.

Answer (score 1):

use a class `ContentValues` to set informations for compile an SQL Statement.

ex:

```
ContentValues content = new ContentValues();
content.putString("name", "Bruce Dickinson");
content.putInt("code", 666);

SqliteDatabase database = helper.getWritableDatabase();
database.insert("tablename", null, content);
```

Comment: Hello and thanks for your answer, I know that option, but my question is more about in what cases I must to use the " or the ' symbols in SQL languaje. Yes, maybe it is a too basic question, but I could not find clear information about it.